# Python and R - Comparing printing a variable

Tags: python, r

In R,

```
a = 10
```

doesn't print anything. But the below prints the value of `a`.

```
(a = 10)
```

Is there something similar in Python? Trying to see if there is a better way than this -

```
a = 10
print(a)
```

Imo, `(a = 10)` is better than

```
a = 10
print(a)
```

Comment: No, there isn't, unless you use the REPL. R is not a general-purpose language in the same way Python is; the vast majority of python code never has to print anything, while you're more likely to want to inspect things in R

Comment: This probably isn't what you're looking for, but you *could* do: `a = 10; a`

Comment: @roganjosh Can you give an example?

Comment: @sacul Yes, I am basically trying to avoid writing 2 lines of code every time I want to see what a variable looks like.

Comment: Are you using an IDE?

Comment: `a = 10; a` can all go on the same line. But honestly I don't think it's pretty code :$

Comment: If you're looking for this kind of interrogation frequently then you'll want an IDE that has IPython built in I.e. Spyder or Enthought Canopy. You can use IPython outside of these but I'm totally gonna stereotype R users and guess they want a scientific IDE that allows this kind of interactive work :)

Comment: @roganjosh I am using Jupyter notebooks but I am open to suggestions for IDEs that can make my life easier.

Comment: @roganjosh I don't like Spyder because the console window has a limited buffer size. In Jupyter, I don't need to worry about that.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @roganjosh Windows, unfortunately.

Comment: Your edit has confused me. What do you mean by limited buffer size? How much are you trying to print?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't, really. I'm going to make some sweeping generalisations (apologies!) but the purpose of the two languages is different; Python is far more general-purpose and `print` like this just wouldn't be massively useful in, say, a giant application because it's slow.

If you want to print things like this on a regular basis, I'm going to guess you're using the scientific stack (`numpy`, `pandas` etc.). You'll want an IDE that supports IPython. Some examples are Spyder (which comes with the Anaconda distribution of python that is pre-loaded with the scientific stack of modules) or Enthought Canopy. Those, at least, I'm familiar with. This will give you an interactive console that is an advanced REPL allowing you to view objects by simply typing their name.

Following your clarifications of a) being on Windows and b) requiring persistent printouts for every object, I really don't think there's an option other than installing Anaconda and using Jupyter. Spyder and Canopy do not have an infinitely-scrolling console of printouts that I'm aware of.

Comment: I am not trying to print large volumes of data. The scenario I am talking about is - I have a Jupyter notebook with a lot of analysis in it. As I print things the course of a day or two, I lose the things I have printed the day I started. This does not happen in Jupyter, but it does in Spyder. Not sure how Enthought Canopy works, but I am assuming it is the same way.

Comment: @Aaron the bad news for you is that brings my answer full circle back to "no, theres no better" sorry. sacul's suggestion may work with Jupyter but it's horrible code that will not do anything useful if you ever export your workbook code

Comment: Lol well, that sucks!

Comment: @Aaron it is a bit of a push to need to see printed outputs indefinitely and still get some fancy syntax for that :) I _could_ well be unaware of something but I'll be honest; I've never seen it before and I'm reasonably confident it doesn't exist. Even if it was a magic method, you're still typing just as much.